# Recovery loop in kubernetes fixed to 6 minutes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

Here is the case, i'm currentlly have a lot of cronjob triggered each hours.
In order not to take all my cluster resources, the pod described to the cronjob is quota restricted to 15 pods in parallel.

It works fine, but when all my pods are finished it take 6 minutes to lauch all pods that wasn't launched previously due to quota restriction.

Does anyone know how to decrease this time (to 1 minute for example) ?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be configurable
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy